# Fuction is printing my char far away from where it's supposed to be

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks

I'm doing a card game for my college and I decided to do the card's design using the ASCII table. I made one function that prints the suits of the cards using Unicode since I couldn't print them just using ASCII, then I tried just calling the function inside my card display but it leaves the spot blank and prints the symbol in the start of the prompt line.
[image: Prompt result]

I tried adding some \t to fix the location problem but instead of moving the symbol only, it moved the whole line.

```
//print the cards suits using Unicode
char suits(int n){
if (n == 1){
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x00020000);
wprintf(L"\x2666");
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
}

 if (n == 2){
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x00020000);
wprintf(L"\x2660");
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
}

 if (n == 3){
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x00020000);
wprintf(L"\x2665");
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
}

 if (n == 4){
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x00020000);
wprintf(L"\x2663");
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
}
};


//chars for the cards design
char r = 196;
char p = 124;
char v = 46;
char cur = 191;
char cul = 218;
char cdr = 217;
char cdl = 192;



void displaycards(int cards){

if (cards == 3){
printf("\t\t\t\t %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c \n",cul,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,cur);
printf("\t\t\t\t %c%d%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c \n",p,4,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,p);
printf("\t\t\t\t %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c \n",p,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,p);
printf("\t\t\t\t %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c \n",p,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,p);
printf("\t\t\t\t %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c \n",p,v,v,v,v,suits(1),v,v,v,v,p);
printf("\t\t\t\t %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c \n",p,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,p);
printf("\t\t\t\t %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c \n",p,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,p);
printf("\t\t\t\t %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%d%c \n",p,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,4,p);
printf("\t\t\t\t %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c \n",cdl,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,cdr);
}
};

displaycards(3);
```

Comment: Stick to plain ASCII and "23456789TJQKA" and "SHDC" ;)

Comment: Sorry if its a noob question but what do you mean with SHDC ?

Comment: Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs

Comment: Oh, got it. Well I could do it but visually wouldn't be cool I think. Also I think its something with the second _setmode I used to print the others ASCII again...just dunno how fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> char suits(int n)
> {
>     wprintf(L"test");
> }
> printf("... %c ...\n",suits(1));
> ```

The function `suits` is supposed to return a character, instead it is printing a string before the first `printf` starts printing anything.

You can solve this by using Unicode everywhere and returning a wide char as expected. Your code appears to be Windows specific. You can use UTF8 for Windows 8 and above, you have to call `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)` and represent UTF8 strings as `u8"♦"`. Or use UTF16 for Windows compatibility as shown below. Note that `suits` is changed to return wide string instead of wide char, that's because Unicode can have up to 4 bytes per character.

```
wchar_t *suits(int s)
{
    switch(s)
    {
    case 0: return L"♠";
    case 1: return L"♥";
    case 2: return L"♦";
    case 3: return L"♣";
    }
    return L"";
}

void displaycards(int number) 
{
    wprintf(L"\t\t\t\t ┌───────────┐ \n");
    wprintf(L"\t\t\t\t │ %d........ │ \n", number);
    wprintf(L"\t\t\t\t │ ......... │ \n");
    wprintf(L"\t\t\t\t │ ......... │ \n");
    wprintf(L"\t\t\t\t │ ... %s ... │ \n", suits(2));
    wprintf(L"\t\t\t\t │ ......... │ \n");
    wprintf(L"\t\t\t\t │ ......... │ \n");
    wprintf(L"\t\t\t\t │ ........%d │ \n", number);
    wprintf(L"\t\t\t\t └───────────┘ \n");
};

int main(void)
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x20000); //_O_U16TEXT = 0x20000
    displaycards(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
                             ┌───────────┐
                             │ 4........ │
                             │ ......... │
                             │ ......... │
                             │ ... ♦ ... │
                             │ ......... │
                             │ ......... │
                             │ ........4 │
                             └───────────┘
```